# Exchange - selecting / changing the email address that is used in the From: header

Tags: exchange

I have an Exchange 2000 server, where users have several smtp email aliases - e.g. mail to both rvanhout@ and roel@ end up in my mailbox. This is easy, through the Exchange Users & Groups interface. 'rvanhout' is my Active Directory domain username, 'roel' is the alias (one of the aliases) I have set up.

However when I *send* mail, the From: header always shows rvanhout@, i.e. the Active Directory domain username. Even when I send mail from my local machine with roel@ in the From: header, Exchange changes it to rvanhout@ when processing it. There are circumstance in which I really want to send mail with roel@ in the From: header, e.g. when unsubscribing from mailing lists that use this email address.

Obviously I could use kludges like using another smtp server for these messages, but I'm annoyed that Exchange is rewriting my headers. On the other hand I guess it can be blamed on my lack of knowledge about Exchange. So, is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of to do this is to create Contacts with the appropriate From addresses and then grant Send As rights to the contacts for your users. Then the users have to manually fill in the From field with the appropriate contact.

JR

Comment: You've got it. It's not particulary easy to train users to do this, but it will work fine. You'll need to remove the addt'l SMTP addresses that are assigned to your mailbox so that they can be assigned to the contact objects.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuantley there is not an easy way to do this. Whilst you are specifying the address you want to send from in the From field, when you actually talk to Exchange to do the sending it does so with your AD account name, and this is what is added to the header.

Exchange 2007 makes it easier to solve this problem with Transport rules, but your a little limited with Exchange 2000.

Answer (score 1):

This product is an add on for exchange/outlook that will allow you to choose the from address. http://www.ivasoft.biz/choosefrom.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem: I have a user aliased with multiple email adresses in his exchange properties. But when I try to set one of the aliases in the client (outlook) all I get is "you are not allowed to send email to this recipient" as ndr mail.

This setup works in another environment so I am not sure what the problem is here...