# Rewrite outgoing mail for Exchange and virtual domains

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, exchange

I have multiple domains that a single exchange install hosts mail for. Here is the scenario:

matt@domainA.com
info@domainB.com
matt@real_company_domain.com

The matt@domainA.com and info@domainB.com are virtual addresses that go to matt@real_company_domain.com

Is it possible to configure exchange to rewrite the outgoing From: so that it comes from whichever domain the original mail was sent to? So if a user emails matt@domainA.com, if I respond right now, it will come from matt@real_company_domain.com. I'd like Exchange to automatically rewrite it to From: matt@domainA.com. If someone emails info@domainB.com, the response is rewritten From: info@domainB.com

I hope that's clear. Is this at all possible? Thanks!

Comment: This is nearly the same question as http://serverfault.com/questions/24624/exchange-selecting-changing-the-email-address-that-is-used-in-the-from-heade

Comment: Yep-- nearly the same question, and the same answers apply.

Answer (score 1):

There's no automated mechanism in any version of Exchange to do what you're looking for if you're determined to bring email for all those addresses into a single mailbox. You're going to be stuck creating "Contact" objects with those alternative addresses assigned to them, configured to deliver incoming to the "real" mailbox. Then, you'll need to grant "Send As" permission on those contact objects to the user of the "real" mailbox who will then have to control the "From:" address in Outlook by choosing the appropriate contact from which to send replies.

There has never been a good "story" from Microsoft to do what you're trying to do with any version of Outlook / Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Choose From](http://www.ivasoft.com/choosefrom2007.shtml)